# How to place a v-btn on v-card next to v-card-text on same row?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify 2 with Vue 2.  Here is some code:

```
<template>
<v-container fluid outlined class = "pt-0 pl-0">
<v-row no-gutters>  
<v-col>
 <v-sheet id="card-1" elevation=0 
   class = "pt-1 pb-0 pl-0 ma-0 black md-2 rounded-0" max-width='500px' >
   <v-card-text class="text-h4 yellow--text font-weight-medium pt-0 pb-0 ma-0">
   Last Refresh:
     </v-card-text>   
   <v-card-text class="text-h3 white--text pt-0 pb-2 ma-0">
   {{lastrefresh}}
     </v-card-text> 
 <v-btn
   color="red"
   dark
   medium
   class="mt-2 mr-4">
   Refresh Data
 </v-btn>
 <v-btn
   color="green"
   dark
   medium
   class="mt-2 mr-4">
   Select Date
 </v-btn>
 </v-sheet>
</v-col>
</v-row>
</v-container>
</template>
```

Here is what is produced:

[image]

What I need is for the red button to be immediately to the right of the text, with the green button to the right of the red button.  Both buttons sharing the black background.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by dividing row into col .

Here is my code :-

```
    <v-row no-gutters  class = "pt-1 pb-0 pl-0 ma-0 black">  
<v-col>
 <v-sheet id="card-1" elevation=0 
    max-width='500px' class = "pt-1 pb-0 pl-0 ma-0 black md-2 rounded-0" >
   <v-card-text class="text-h4 yellow--text font-weight-medium pt-0 pb-0 ma-0">
   Last Refresh:
     </v-card-text>   
   <v-card-text class="text-h3 white--text pt-0 pb-2 ma-0">
   {{lastrefresh}}
     </v-card-text> 
   </v-col>
  <v-col >
 <v-btn
   color="red"
   dark
   medium
   class="mt-2 mr-4">
   Refresh Data
 </v-btn>
 <v-btn
   color="green"
   dark
   medium
   class="mt-2 mr-4">
   Select Date
 </v-btn>
 </v-sheet>
</v-col>
</v-row>
```

[this](https://codepen.io/nilesh9836/pen/jOZbNEy?editors=101) is the link for codepen.

Comment: The answer above got me in the ballpark.  after some experimentation, I got very close to what I had planned.   I eliminate the v-sheet and styled the row per the codepen shown by Nilesh, and then I was able to pull the buttons over to the left more by using v-col with the right number of cols and the align keyword (e.g. align="left").

I think this technique will serve well.